# How can FPGA differential signal use lower power when it has two lines instead of one?

Tags: fpga, differential, power-dissipation

I am a bit confused about differential signaling on FPGAs. I am trying to figure out how does power dissipation in FPGA differential signaling compare with power dissipation in FPGA single ended signaling.

As far as I am aware, the differential signal mechanism is emulated i.e we may not have a true differential signal buffer in the FPGA but rather drive two single ended buffers in opposite directions. How does grounding affect this mechanism?

I/O buffers dissipate power when they switch output state. With differential buffers, there are always going to be two buffers that are switching simultaneously. Shouldn't this cause the use of differential signal to dissipate more power than single ended signals?

Comment: You assume if differential transmission is emulated on FPGAs. What if it isn't? LVDS, CML and other differential tranceivers do exist in FPGAs and they can be driven with high speed serdes blocks. Differential signaling usually uses low voltages (where LVDS gets its name) so a swing of few hundred millivolts is a lot less that few volts swing of CMOS. That offsets the power to the benefit of high speed differential communications at lower voltages.

Comment: If two drivers are used then sure, the dissipation is twice but, what initially made you doubt this? Or, what prompted you to ask this question?

Comment: The question is, will using differential signalling lead to lower power dissipation in a design or not? I have heard that differential signals dissipate low power. However, is this true for the way differential signals are generated inside FPGA buffers? We are working on a battery powered device and thus want lower power dissipation. Somebody mentioned that since differential signals use 2 lines, it shall lead to double power dissipation. There are supposed to be 10+ signals that can be connected via differential or single ended signalling so this question is important to answer now.

Comment: Time to hit the datasheets in that case, the fpga vendors have book sized datasheets giving the static and dynamic power consumption figures for the available IO blocks in multiple configurations. This will strongly depend on the specifics of a vendors implementation. Most FPGAs have real differential drivers and receivers available, which can be the efficient choice at high speed as the low signal levels reduce termination power, but a slow signal might be better single ended because the lack of termination and differential amplifier will make the static power savings beat the dynamic ones.